# jQuery Datatables simulate tr click fails

Tags: jquery, datatables

DataTables v1.10.0:

I am trying to simulate a `click` event on the first row. Every other aspect of the table is working fine. I tried to add a class instead of triggering a click and it works fine. But no triggering.

```
$("#v-table").on("init.dt", function() {            
        $("#v-table").find("tbody tr:eq(0)").trigger("click");              
}).DataTable({
        "pagingType": "simple"
});
```

The Click handler:

```
$('#v-table tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {            
        console.log("hello, why click thee?");
    });
```

Comment: I recommend to state the version in dataTable related questions, since there has been a major change recently. This way you won't get two different answers like Vickels 1.10 answer and the one from fortiZ which is correct for older versions.

Comment: @mainguy, Why do you say initComplete is for older versions? http://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete

Comment: I said Correct. Look at this Plunker for version 1.94 which was the stable Version 2 months ago: http://plnkr.co/edit/fNNCCLpKDaXvzKh1O5vy?p=preview Here are the callback manuals for the older versions: http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/callbacks

Comment: Oh, now I see that in the manual the old Callbacks are now described under Reference/Options and the .on handlers under Manual/Events. Although dataTables rocks, the manual sometimes doesn't :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to trigger a click event while init, you could try to trigger the click after the initialisation is completed:

```
    $("#v-table").DataTable({
            "pagingType": "simple",
            "initComplete": function() {
                   $("#v-table").find("tbody tr:eq(0)").trigger("click");
            }
    });
```

[DataTables - initComplete](http://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that at Datatable init, the click handler is not ready yet. you have to call it during the init:

```
$("#v-table").on('init.dt', function () {

  handler();
  $("#v-table").find("tbody tr:eq(0)").trigger("click");
}).DataTable({
  "pagingType": "simple"
});

function handler() {
    $('#v-table tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
    console.log("hello, why click thee?");
 })
};
```

here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DALEc/